# IXWebSocket wss c++ client cannot connect to Node.js wss server using an ip address

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl

I have a *IXWebSocket* c++ wss client connecting to a *Node.js* wss server([websocket npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)). Everything is fine as long as the client connect to `"wss://localhost:8080"`. Soon as I use the ip address of the *Node.js* wss server, I have the error "*OpenSSL failed - error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed*"

### Certificate chain creation

I created my own private root ca.  I used those commands to generate *root ca* key/certificate and *server* key/certificate:

```
$ openssl genpkey -aes256 -out root-ca/private/ca.private.key -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
$ openssl req -config root-ca/root-ca.conf -key root-ca\private\ca.private.key -x509 -days 7500 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -out root-ca\certs\ca.crt
$ openssl genpkey -out server/private/server.private.key -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
$ openssl req -key server\private\server.private.key -new -sha256 -out server\csr\server.csr
$ openssl ca -config root-ca\root-ca.conf -extensions server_cert -days 365 -notext -in server\csr\server.csr -out server\certs\server.crt
```

The configuration has a `subjectAltName` for both root and server and it looks like this :

```
[ca]
#\\root\\ca\\root-ca\\root-ca.conf
#see man ca
default_ca                      =       CA_default
                
[CA_default]                
dir                             =       C:\\ca\\root-ca
certs                           =       $dir\\certs
crl_dir                         =       $dir\\crl
new_certs_dir                   =       $dir\\newcerts
database                        =       $dir\\index
serial                          =       $dir\\serial
RANDFILE                        =       $dir\\private\\.rand
                
private_key                     =       $dir\\private\\ca.private.key
certificate                     =       $dir\\certs\\ca.crt
                
crlnumber                       =       $dir\\crlnumber
crl                             =       $dir\\crl\\ca.crl
crl_extensions                  =       crl_ext
default_crl_days                =       30
                
default_md                      =       sha256
                
name_opt                        =       ca_default
cert_opt                        =       ca_default
default_days                    =       365
preserve                        =       no
policy                          =       policy_loose
            
[ policy_strict ]           
countryName                     =       supplied
stateOrProvinceName             =       supplied
organizationName                =       match
organizationalUnitName          =       optional
commonName                      =       supplied
emailAddress                    =       optional
            
[ policy_loose ]            
countryName                     =       optional
stateOrProvinceName             =       optional
localityName                    =       optional
organizationName                =       optional
organizationalUnitName          =       optional
commonName                      =       supplied
emailAddress                    =       optional

[ req ]
# Options for the req tool, man req.
default_bits                    =       2048
distinguished_name              =       req_distinguished_name
string_mask                     =       utf8only
default_md                      =       sha256
# Extension to add when the -x509 option is used.
x509_extensions                 =       v3_ca

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     =       Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName             =       State or Province Name
localityName                    =       Locality Name
0.organizationName              =       Organization Name
organizationalUnitName          =       Organizational Unit Name
commonName                      =       Common Name
emailAddress                    =       Email Address
countryName_default             =       CA
stateOrProvinceName_default     =       Qc
0.organizationName_default      =       Adacel

[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions to apply when createing root ca
# Extensions for a typical CA, man x509v3_config
subjectKeyIdentifier            =       hash
authorityKeyIdentifier          =       keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints                =       critical, CA:true
keyUsage                        =       critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign
subjectAltName                  =       @alt_names

[ v3_intermediate_ca ]
# Extensions to apply when creating intermediate or sub-ca
# Extensions for a typical intermediate CA, same man as above
subjectKeyIdentifier            =       hash
authorityKeyIdentifier          =       keyid:always,issuer
#pathlen:0 ensures no more sub-ca can be created below an intermediate
basicConstraints                =       critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage                        =       critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ server_cert ]
# Extensions for server certificates
basicConstraints                =       CA:FALSE
nsCertType                      =       server
nsComment                       =       "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier            =       hash
authorityKeyIdentifier          =       keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage                        =       critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage                =       serverAuth
subjectAltName                  =       @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1                           =       localhost
IP.1                            =       192.168.230.138
IP.2                            =       127.0.0.1
```

The certificate chain looks valid between my *root ca* and my *server*:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile root-ca\certs\ca.crt server\certs\server.crt
server\certs\server.crt: OK
```

Both `ca.crt` and `server.crt` have a reference to the wss server IP address, I used the `subjectAltName` parameter to defined it. I thought that my *root ca* would need it (I am not even sure that make sense to have domain on the *root ca*), but it doesn't make any difference.

### What is not working

**My IXWebSocket c++ client :**

```
ix::initNetSystem();
ix::WebSocket webSocket;
ix::SocketTLSOptions tlsOptions;
tlsOptions.caFile = "ca.crt";
webSocket.setTLSOptions(tlsOptions);
std::string url("wss://localhost:8080");
//std::string url("wss://192.168.230.138:8080"); //Cannot connect to the ip
webSocket.setUrl(url);
```

### What is working

**wss javascript client:**

I also coded a javascript client (using same npm package as my server, not ) and this little client can connect using the ip address!!

```
const options = {
  ca: fs.readFileSync("./ca.crt"),
};

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on("connectFailed", function (error) {
  console.log("Connect Error: " + error.toString());
});

client.on("connect", function (connection) {
  console.log("WebSocket Client Connected");
  connection.on("error", function (error) {
    console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
  });
  connection.on("close", function () {
    console.log("echo-protocol Connection Closed");
  });
  connection.on("message", function (message) {
    if (message.type === "utf8") {
      console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
    }
  });
});

client.connect("wss://192.168.230.138:8080/", null, null, null, options);
```

**My Node.js server :**

```
const httpsSignalServer = https.createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./server.private.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./server.crt"),
  },
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(`signal server : we have received the request ${req}`);
  }
);
const signalWebsocket = new WebSockerServer.server({
  httpServer: httpsSignalServer,
});
signalWebsocket.on("request", (request) => onRequest(request));
httpsSignalServer.listen(8080, () =>
  console.log("---> My signal server is listening <---")
);

signalWebsocket.on("request", (request) => onRequest(request));

httpsSignalServer.listen(8080, () =>
  console.log("---> My signal server is listening <---")
);
```

### Questions :

1. Any idea why my c++ client cannot connect using an ip address to the server, while the javascript client can? (using the same certificate chain)
2. If no, any idea how I could debug this?
3. Would it be possible that the problem is a high level SSL stuff, where you actually need a real hostname and can't use an IP?